# Python syntax error: Unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

When i run this code in python 3.9 I get the syntax error stated in the title. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def grid():
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = "_"
    print(a,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i, sep = '|')   

grid()
```

Comment: If you want to print a newline, you need to print `"\n"` as its own element, as in `print(a, b, c, "\n")`.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @chemicalwill my expected output was a simple design and its solved.
`_|_|_
_|_|_
_|_|_`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`\` is a line continuation character. `n` is the character that follows it, and it is unexpected, because `\` must be the last character in a line. See: [Python language reference – Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).

If you meant to insert line breaks in the `print` output, the line break character is itself a string, `'\n'`, not part of the Python syntax.

Either use string concatenation:

```
print(a, b, c + '\n' + d, e, f + '\n' + g, h, i, sep = '|')
```

Or just call `print` multiple times, as it automatically adds a line break:

```
print(a, b, c, sep = '|')
print(d, e, f, sep = '|')
print(g, h, i, sep = '|')
```